# Redundant if statement?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, trim

Is the `if` statement in the following example redundant?

```
if (str[0] === ' ') {
  str = str.trimStart()
}
```

It seems unnecessary to me since `trimStart()` does not seem to have any negative effect on a string without a space at the beginning. Additionally, if the string does have a space at the beginning, you are running twice as many operations as needed.

Is the `if` statement ever necessary in situations like the one above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` is not necessary, but you should save the trimmed value somewhere, like

```
str = str.trimStart();
```

-- Edit --

"Is the 'if' ever necessary...?"

The test that you are doing in the original is redundant. But you might want to check that str has a value and/or check that this value is a string before calling trimStart(), like

```
if (str && typeof str === 'string') ...
```

Comment: its derived from an `input` element, so itll always have a value. good suggestion nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

Given the edited code, there's one situation where the `if` statement could be useful - if the string starts with a newline (which counts as whitespace, and would be trimmed), not a plain space. For example:

```js
const parseStr = (str) => {
  if (str[0] === ' ') {
    str = str.trimStart()
  }
  console.log(str.length);
};
parseStr('\nfoo');
parseStr(' foo');
parseStr('foo');
```

If `trimStart` was called unconditionally, the newline would be trimmed regardless:

```js
const parseStr = (str) => {
  str = str.trimStart()
  console.log(str.length);
};
parseStr('\nfoo');
parseStr(' foo');
parseStr('foo');
```

Comment: sorry, yeah the other guy who answered pointed that out too. i edited the Q

Comment: It could make a difference if the string started with a newline. A bit odd, but not impossible.

Comment: thanks so much for your input (no pun intended lol). i selected the other guys because he beat you by a hair, although your answer is just as useful

Answer (score 1):

The if block isn't necessary since the `trimStart` function won't have any effect if there is not space in the beginning of the string. Having the if statement does not have any effect over it and wouldn't really have any real performance benefits either.

Comment: i know the performance gain would be negligible, but youre still running twice as many operations as necessary

Comment: You will only run twice as many operation if the string has a space in the beginning, if it doesn't then it wouldn't call the `trimStart` function. Calling a function does have some overhead compared to if statements, but they don't really make any meaningful differences.

Comment: that is true. but resolving the `if` statement is basically an operation in and of itself. anyways, now i got my answer. ty